# Details of duality of Streams and Tables in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The confluent document [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#duality-of-streams-and-tables) states

> And Kafka exploits this duality in many ways: for example, to make your applications elastic, to support fault-tolerant stateful processing, or to run Kafka Streams Interactive Queries against your application’s latest processing results.

Wonder if there are more details for how is the duality of streams/tables used in these scenarios. Looking for some simple explanation rather than some long design docs

Answer (score 0):

A stream can be considered as *log* and table ***can*** be a *snapshot* of logs at a given instant of time.

A stream is a flow of data, new data can keep on coming and we process it as it comes, store the processed results in a table for querying.

A table's data, ***changes*** over time. At any given instant of time, we get a snapshot of that data at that instant. A table, therefore, can be used for performing queries and retreiving results on demand, which is not the case with ***'just' streams***

---

For example,

**User comments** on a *video* can be a *stream* of events, new comments keep on coming and they simply get displayed on the UI. Nothing to query here (typically).

But there also some other use cases, like..

**Cricket updates:** For every new ball, we get no. of runs for that ball, now we need to add them to the score. We certainly, need to store the previous score and update it with every new ball. We also need to query the score at any given instant of time (on demand). For performing queries or updating the score, we can use a table.

---

In the Kafka context, event is a log message and every message is *immutable*.
Consider an example, of an user information getting updated.

```
{user_id: 101, name: X}
{user_id: 101, name: Y}
```

The `name` of the `user_id=101` is updated from `X` to `Y`. When you perform the update on a database directly and do a query, you see only `name: Y`, you may not have the previous name of the user with you, because it is *overridden* with the new value.

In Kafka, we have two messages, `'X'` and `'Y'`.

At times, this may be useful and even critical. A hacker could have changed all the user information, and the legit user has no way of proving his identity to re-claim his account. But if there is previous info about his account which he can tell as a proof, he can re-claim it.

So for those who use Kafka, there could be use-cases to store data as a table (or) a map and then retrieve it using queries.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this seems not directly answering my question

Comment: @delbao could you elaborate it further then?